# не могу запускать веб-сервис на сервере

Tags: linux, delphi, apache, cgi

В Delphi 10.1 Berlin создаю веб-сервис(DLL-файл) и копирую на хост-сервер в каталоге home/public_html/cgi-bin  но потом никак не могу запускать.
в браузере пищу:

> http://domain_name/cgi-bin/mod_ap.dll/wsdl

и в ответ получаю

> Your connection is not secure. The owner of (domain_name) has configured
>   their website improperly. To protect your information from being
>   stolen, Firefox has not connected to this website.

если этот файл добавляю в exception тогда уже выводит:

> lscgid: execve():/home/.../public_html/cgi-bin/mod_ap.dll: Exec format
>   error

как прочитал это может быть от несовместимости оперативных систем. Файл создаётся в delphi а на сервере установлена оперативная система Centos(Linux) и сервер litespeed(Linux). Должен файл созданный в Delphi for windows запускаться на linux? Почкму html и другие файлы открываются на сервере? Или что-то сильно путаю!

Answer (score 1):

Этот файл, действительно, должен быть скомпилирован для ОС Linux. Под Linux Delphi умеет компилировать только начиная с версии 10.2 (Tokyo)

html файлы открываются, потому что это не исполняемые файлы

Comment: Anton Shchyrov спасибо за ответ. 
получается что datasnap тоже не будет работать на сервере где ОС linux установлена, посколко в случае datasnap тоже исполняемый exe надо опубликовать на сервере. Правильно я вас понял?
И последный вопрос-как обстоит дела в Visual studio 2017 в смысле совместимости  не знаете?

Comment: @basti Везде дела обстоят одинаково - исполняемый файл, а также dll/so должны быть откомпилированы под ту платформу, где они будут использоваться. А дальше смотрите описание компилятора - умеет ли он компилировать под целевую платформу или нет

Comment: Anton Shchyrov т.е. те приложения которые находятся на серверах где ОС linux- 
а) созданы в среде linux или 
б) созданы в среде windows и потом перекомпилированы на компиляторах под linux?

Comment: @basti Не важно в какой среде созданы. Важно как скомпилированы. Например Delphi IDE - это 32 разрядное Windows приложение. Но оно может компилировать под Win32, Win64, iOS, Android, Linux

Comment: Anton Shchyrov последный вопрос и больше не буду беспокойть: есть клиентская программа на Delphi пол виндоус. Сейчас должен добавить web-service программу. Суть программы- переслать данные из бд клиента к серверу (xml-пакетамы). Но получается что клиентская часть остаётся на клиенте а серверная часть(интерфейс) после получения в Delphi потом снова перекомпилируется под линукс и загружаю на сервер. 
Серверную часть надо связывать с бд Mysql и серверная часть будеть вставыть записы в бд. Правильно я рассуждаю?

Comment: @basti Задайте это отдельным вопросом

Comment: Хорошо. Отдельный пост напишу. Спасибо!